# onclick event not work in phone gap android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

i have create a app. in phoneGap. it work fine on iphone but in android click event not work.
have any idea what is wrong in my code

this is my html:-

```
<div   id="logInScreen">
        <div class="logInScreen">
            <a class="main_logo" href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt=""/></a>
            <p class="main_text">Digital Discount Vouchers <br /> On Your Phone</p>
            <div id ="divRegister" class="main_reg" onclick="GeneralTransit('#register')">Register</div>
            <div id ="divNotNow" class="main_reg" onclick="GeneralTransit('#t_featured')">Not Now...</div>
            <div  id ="divLogin" class="main_reg" onclick="GeneralTransit('#login')">Login</div>
            <div class="main_forgot" onclick="GeneralTransit('#login_fog')">FORGOT PASSWORD?</div>
            <p class="main_text2">IN ORDER TO PURCHASE ADDITIONAL VOUCHERS <br /> YOU NEED TO BE REGISTERED</p>
            <p class="main_text3">POWERED BY YALLAMOB.COM</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

there is also some other div's that hide and show on conditions .

Answer (score -1):

I thought it was the missing `';'` (`GeneralTransit('#register');`)

But it works here with and without the';': http://jsfiddle.net/ZVFgW/11/

Your problem is likely somewhere else. 
Did you debug it using Chrome or Firefox+Firebug?

Comment: Works on my HTC Desire with Cyanogenmod (Android 2.3) and Asus Transformer (Android 4.0.3).